# How to test jQueryUI dialog with selenium IDE in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, selenium

I am trying to record a functional test with selenium IDE plug in for Firefox. I am testing in the login functionality of an asp.net MVC application.
But it is not picking up the username and password.

---

```
[info] Executing: |open | / | |
[info] Executing: |click | id=loginLink | |
[info] Executing: |type | id=UserName | admin |
[error] Element id=UserName not found
```

The username and password is displayed using The from account controller, jsonlogon  is partial displayed with jQueryUI dialog.

How could i get it to read the username and password?

Comment: I added an actual question. Might want to re-word it if it is not what you want

Comment: thanks..that is what i want to ask